# Calling a .jar from ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, instantiation

I have a .jar file that i've placed in my D:\Coldfusion8\wwwroot\web-inf\lib\ directory.  The file is abcdef.jar

This is my first time doing this, not sure what the path should be in my createObject().

```
<cfset abcObj = createObject("java","com.abcdef") />
<cfset result = acbObj.doStuff("123456") />
```

But when I run it, I get

```
Object Instantiation Exception.
Class not found: com.vp4jo_b
```

What am I missing in the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you restarted the Coldfusion Service?

Even when in the class path, jars are only loaded at server start.

Info moved up from the comments:

- Make sure the file is in the System class path, or in the one of the configured class paths of ColdFusion.
- As for the class name parameter of `CreateObject()`: The class name starts within the jar. Open it like a .zip file and look at its structure. The dotted path mimics the folder structure, so if the Server still complains, you must be missing something in the dotted path.

Comment: I have.  My confusion comes in where the "com" starts.  I got that from an example on the web.  As I said, my .jar is in D:\Coldfusion8\lib\

Comment: The "com" starts within the jar. Open it like a .zip file and look at its structure. The dotted path mimics the folder structure, so you must be missing something in the path.

Comment: Ok, so going back, where do I tell Coldfusion to even look for the .jar file?

Comment: Nevermind.  I had the .jar in the wrong directory.  I moved it, restarted CF, followed your advice about the Path, fixed my createObject and Voila... THanks!

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered using [JavaLoader](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/)?

Comment: JavaLoader is definitely the way to go.  That way you can place the Java class/lib where you like rather than relying on the class path for your specific installation.